# How to save and restore partitioned variable in Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a large matrix.

I use bellow way create this variable as number of shards.

```
softmax_w = tf.get_variable("softmax_w", [hps.vocab_size, hps.projected_size],
                            partitioner=tf.fixed_size_partitioner(hps.num_shards, 0))
```

create log:

```
model/softmax_w/part_0:0 (99184, 512) /cpu:0
model/softmax_w/part_1:0 (99184, 512) /cpu:0
model/softmax_w/part_2:0 (99184, 512) /cpu:0
model/softmax_w/part_3:0 (99184, 512) /cpu:0
model/softmax_w/part_4:0 (99184, 512) /cpu:0
model/softmax_w/part_5:0 (99184, 512) /cpu:0
model/softmax_w/part_6:0 (99183, 512) /cpu:0
model/softmax_w/part_7:0 (99183, 512) /cpu:0
```

I can training and save it success. But when I try to restore model I got this error:

```
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Key model/softmax_w/part_7 not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Key model/softmax_w/part_6 not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Key model/softmax_w/part_5 not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Key model/softmax_w/part_4 not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Key model/softmax_w/part_3 not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Key model/softmax_w/part_2 not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Key model/softmax_w/part_1 not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Key model/softmax_w/part_0 not found in checkpoint
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Not found: Key model/softmax_w/part_7 not found in checkpoint
```

I found tensorflow save the variable as a part. The saved parameter just have one `softmax_w`. No longer a partitioned variable.

Answer (score 1):

It happened in tensorflow 0.12 and doesn't happen in 1.3 (the last version as of October 2017). Here a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6551), filed by the same author and now fixed. So if you see this error, just upgrade tensorflow.